# Drawing a bitmap image into Pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am a beginner to Python, and working through Eric Matthes' Python Crash Course. I am struggling on Exercise 12-2, in which you have to use a class to add a character sprite into a pygame window. The terminal tells me "init missing positional argument 'screen'" but when I put `skel = Skel(screen)` it says "name 'screen' is not defined" at line 23. Here is all of the code

```
import sys
import pygame

class Skel():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        #Initialize skeleteon and set screen
        self.screen = screen

        #Get rectangle of skeleton and screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load("EM17_skeleton.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #Place skeleton at center
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.centery

    def draw(self,screen):
        """Draw skeleton at location"""
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

skel = Skel(screen)

def run_game(self):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

    #Set background color
    bg_color = (0,0,160)

    #Set loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        skel.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when the code creates the instance of `Skel`, the parameter `screen` has not been defined yet.   `screen` is defined lower down in the `run_game()` function.

```
skel = Skel(screen)  # <-- HERE

def run_game(self):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))  # <-- AND HERE

    #Set background color
    bg_color = (0,0,160)

    #Set loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        skel.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Moving the initialisation of `skel` into that function will fix it.

```
def run_game(self):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))  
    skel = Skel(screen)                          # <-- HERE

    #Set background color
    bg_color = (0,0,160)

    #Set loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        skel.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```